# How do I get database response time in Rails console on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

When I make querys in the rails console in development on each query I get a speed report such as (0.4ms in this case):

```
Comment.find(1)
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

But if I make that exact same query in the rails console on heroku, then I get the result but no report.

Is there some way to add a trace or log call of some sort to get this information on querying the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, heroku runs your code in *production* environment (environment variable RAILS_ENV is set to "production"). For production environment Rails defaults to "INFO" log level, whereas in "development" it is set to "DEBUG".

You can override the log level right from the rails console:

```
Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```